# How to print $_GET[] value

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass `$_GET` value to `window.open`, but how?

My current code can't pass `$_GET` value:

```
function googlemap() {
    ver id = <? php print ''.$_GET['buid'].''; ?>

    window.open("Views/Admin/addresstomap.php?bid=+id", "myWindow",
        "status = 0, height = 600, width = 800, resizable = 0 top=200, left=300,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, ")
}
```

Comment: Try changing `bid=+id"` to `bid="+id`. That looks like the only problem, I think.

Comment: You need to change `ver` to `var`.

Comment: Why even assign it as a variable? Just echo it out directly into the window.open string.

Comment: @Jako There is the possibility that there is more code in `googlemap()` which uses `id`, but unless that is so, you're quite right.

Comment: @Jako: While correct, in general a variable does allow you to interrogate the value if you want to validate it before passing it on. I would also assume this: `"Views/Admin/addresstomap.php?bid=" + id` is more readable at no heavy cost.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I agree. Just giving an alternate option for this specific example.

Answer (score 5):

You're not using the variable in the `window.open` call, you're just using a string with the name of the variable:

```
"Views/Admin/addresstomap.php?bid=+id"
```

JavaScript won't interpret `id` from that string.  You need to separate it from the string itself:

```
"Views/Admin/addresstomap.php?bid=" + id
```

Additionally, you have a typo in the `var` keyword and you're missing a semi-colon.  This:

```
ver id=<?php print''.$_GET['buid'].''; ?>
```

should be this:

```
var id=<?php print''.$_GET['buid'].''; ?>;
```

Indeed, you may even need quotes around it if the variable is supposed to be a string.  (I don't know if it is, but you should be able to figure it out.)  In that case the line would be:

```
var id="<?php print''.$_GET['buid'].''; ?>";
```

(Note: Given these errors, there may still be others that I haven't noticed.  You'll want to do some debugging, check your PHP logs, check your JavaScript console, etc.)